# How to load multiple scripts inside a q-script?

Tags: kdb

I would like to load multiple scripts inside the same script:

I can run this:

```
\l first_script.q
/ more q code
```

But if I try to run this:

```
\l first_script.q;
\l second_script.q;
/ more q code
```

... it parses ';' as part of the file name. Does anyone know a way to load multiple q-files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `system` to load the files :

```
system "l first_script.q";
system "l second_script.q";
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also drop the `;` at the end of your lines

```
\l first_script.q
\l second_script.q
```

`q` doesn't need these to be present when loading scripts

Comment: That apparently only works inside a script that only has one \l statement. I I try this, I get: ERROR: 'nyi 
(not yet implemented. Interpret as "it probably makes sense, but it's not defined nor implemented, and needs more thinking about as the language evolves".)

Comment: ```\l first_script.q
\l second_script.q```
this format should work (with a newline between the first and second lines, I have tested on my own console). The only error I could see would be coming from the contents of these scripts or from the code you have following these lines

Comment: @Chris in what version of kdb do you get the error? It should apparently work: https://github.com/psaris/funq/blob/master/funq.q#L1-L4